# How to add some literal in console with console.log (or another command) command in same line?

Tags: javascript

How to print some literal in console with console.log (or another command) command in **same line**?

For example:

```
print 1;
print 2;
print 3;
```

**Console output: 123**

Comment: Totally unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is simple not possible or for at least in the browsers I use (chrome, ff, edge, ie). The closest possibility would be `console.log(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Maybe there is some another command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood you correctly, you want a JavaScript equivalent of C#'s `Console.Write`, that appends (a) character(s) to the last line.

That's not possible.

The moment something is logged to the console, you no longer have access to it. You can't "append" to a logged line, you can't change it.

---

That said, you could write a wrapper that sortof emulates this behavior:

```js
let logTimeout;        // Keep track of the pending timeout
let logArguments = []; // Keep track of the passed loggable arguments


function log(...args) {
  if (logTimeout) {
    logTimeout = clearTimeout(logTimeout);  // Reset the timeout if it's pending.
  }

  logArguments = logArguments.concat(args); // Add the new arguments.
  
  logTimeout = setTimeout(() => {           // Log all arguments after a short delay.
    console.log(...logArguments);
    logArguments.length = 0;
  });
}

log(1);
log(2);
log(3);
log("foo");
log("bar");
log({crazy: "stuff"});

setTimeout(() => {
  log(4);
  log(5);
  log(6);
  log("baz");
  log("woo");
  log([{crazier: "stuff"}]);
}, 500);
```

Just note that this logger is asynchronous. This means your code that calls `log` will run to completion before something is actually logged.

Comment: Tell me please, the "..." in arguments is the new feature in ES6?

Comment: Yes it is, it's the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). It's quite nifty!

Comment: Cool. Thank you!